# How to Move files to the recycle bin

Tags: c#, recycle-bin

I need to Move a file to recycle bin in .net 2003

I added microsft.visualbasic.runtime dll from refrence, but I could not able to get filesystem.deletedirectory, So what to do..Can any one help me?

Comment: Have you tried Google? http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+delete+file+to+recycle+bin

Comment: There really should be a "too easy to find on Google" reason for closing a question.

Comment: agreed, you really should try google first. Or at least report what you've tried?

Comment: I also agree with Matt on this. Chances are this guy just registered to ask this, then finds the answer before he gets and answer here, and then is never heard from again.

Comment: NOW you're talking, guys! I've always discouraged easily Google-able questions.

Comment: This question WAS the top result on Google when I searched.  Isn't the point of stackoverflow to be a comprehensive database of programmer questions and answers, rather than to simply fill in the gaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send a File to the Recycle Bin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282418/send-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin)

Answer (score 24):

I found this, don't know if it works, but it's worth a shot.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

string path = @"c:\myfile.txt";
FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(path, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
```

EDIT: Wise words from Nifle:
Just remember to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: +1 This does indeed work. I was just going to post the same answer myself.

Comment: Just remember to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: Btw, it uses P/Invoke, as it seems from Reflector

Answer (score 2):

Basically, between the reference at the top and actually calling the method you need the full name (after adding the library of course)

You can either fully call it:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(
    path,
    FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,
    RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
```

---

OR you can add the reference to the top with the others:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
```

and then

```
FilesSystem.DeleteDirectory( etc );
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.daveamenta.com/2008-05/c-delete-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin/) might help you.  Looks like you need to either add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll or use P/Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
```

at the top of your page?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(path, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
```

needs: `00:00:00.4036573` to delete one file. Using

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SHFileOperation(ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT FileOp);
```

only needs: `00:00:00.1107684` to delete one file.

An implementation can be found there:
[Send a File to the Recycle Bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282418/visual-c-sharp-send-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin)

Comment: @xmenW.K. Sorry, it's to long ago but I think I used 1000 generated files and devided the time that was used to delete them to get an average time ;-)